# Als vs denn, what's the difference?

Tags: conjunction

What's the difference between the conjunctions als and denn? How do you know when to use one over the other? Can denn be used in a sentence like

> Besser zu süß als zu bitter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the **comparision particle** *als* you have there, not the conjunction. These particles are never leading a subclause, that's how you spot them:

> Besser zu süß **als** zu bitter.
>
> Besser zu süß **denn** zu bitter.

*Better too sweet **than** too bitter.*

The meaning is exactly the same here but **denn** sounds a bit odd and old-fashioned. In some phrases however **denn** is more common.

> Es ist **mehr denn je** nötig.

*It's necessary **more than ever**.*

Sometimes *denn* and *als* are combined.

> Ich nahm sie **weniger als** Kollegin wahr **denn als** Freundin.
>
> Ich nahm sie **weniger als** Kollegin wahr **als als** Freundin. **(bad!)**

*Ich recognized her **less as** a colleague **than as** a friend.*

The latter sentence uses the *als* *three times*, and one time twice in a row. That's too much even for German speakers (who love repetitions).

---

The **conjunctions** *als* und *denn* are leading a subclause:

> Sie stieg aus, **als** die Bahn anhielt.

*She stepped off **when** the trolley stopped.*

> Sie stieg aus, **denn** die Bahn hielt an.

*She stepped off **because** the trolley stopped.*

Comment: If I remember my school grammar correctly, _denn_ actually leads a full clause, which is why you don't get SOV order in the denn-sentence. (That is, _denn die Bahn hielt an_, not _denn die Bahn anhielt_.)

Comment: I disagree with your assessment that “als als” is bad.